# Are questions about cell phone CPUs on-topic here?

Tags: support, asking-questions, on-topic

I would like to ask a question about the available selection of cell phone CPUs (systems-on-a-chip). Would it be on-topic on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?

Comment: Sounds like a shopping question. Can you be more specific about the nature of your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that questions about cell phone CPUs are subject to the same rules as every other type of CPU - shopping questions are off-topic, but design questions are fine.

Comment: What is a 'shopping question' and is there a place where those would be on-topic?

Comment: A question asking about part selection. Usually these questions are very specific and will be obsolete (by newer parts and parts becoming end-of-life) within a couple of years.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I was going to ask is a shopping question, then. Unfortunately, I can't see a way to re-phrase it so that it will have an enduring value. But, maybe I can re-phrase it like 'What are the reasons the selection of SoC is power in this regard?'